# Using grep vs awk

Tags: linux, awk, grep, performance

To capture a particular pattern, `awk` and `grep` can be used. Why should we use one over the other? Which is faster and why?

If I had a log file and I wanted to grab a certain pattern, I could do one of the following

```
awk '/pattern/' /var/log/messages
```

or

```
grep 'pattern' /var/log/messages
```

I haven't done any benchmarking, so I wouldn't know. Can someone elaborate this?  It is great to know the inner workings of these two tools.

Comment: Precede any command, even shell scripts, with the `time` command to time how long it takes to run the command. Ex: `time ls -l`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

grep will most likely be faster:

```
# time awk '/USAGE/' imapd.log.1 | wc -l
73832

real    0m2.756s
user    0m2.740s
sys     0m0.020s

# time grep 'USAGE' imapd.log.1 | wc -l
73832

real    0m0.110s
user    0m0.100s
sys     0m0.030s
```

awk is a interpreted programming language, where as grep is a compiled c-code program (which is additionally optimized towards finding patterns in files).

(Note - I ran both commands twice so that caching would not potentially skew the results)

More details about [interpreted languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language) on wikipedia.

As Stephane has rightly pointed out in comments, your mileage may vary due to the implementation of the grep and awk you use, the operating system it is on and the character set you are processing.

Comment: Without saying what grep or awk implementation you're using and on what computer architecture, and with which system character set, those timings have little value.

Comment: the second command will also use the newly cached version. I dont doubt that grep is quicker but not by as much as your numbers show.

Comment: (hence running awk, grep, awk, grep and posting the results from the second set of awk and grep :) and FYI, I live in a UTF8 locale.

Comment: Funny enough, with the BSD tools (on a Mac), awk (31.74s) is slightly faster than sed (33.34s), which is slightly faster than grep (34.21s). Gnu awk owns them all at 5.24s, I don't have gnu grep or sed to test.

Comment: grep should be slightly faster because awk does more with each input line than just search for a regexp in it, e.g. if a field is referenced in the script (which it's not in this case) awk will split each input line into fields based on the field-separator value and it populates builtin variables. but with what you posted there should be almost no difference. By far **the** most important difference between grep and awk wrt matching regexps is that grep searches the whole line for a matching string while awk can search specific fields and so provide more precision and fewer false matches.

Answer (score 16):

Use the most specific and expressive tool. The tool that best fits your use case is likely to be the fastest.

As a rough guide:

- searching for lines matching a substring or regexp? Use grep.
- selecting certain columns from a simply-delimited file? Use cut.
- performing pattern-based substitutions or ... other stuff sed can reasonably do? Use sed.
- need some combination of the above 3, or printf formatting, or general purpose loops and branches? Use awk.

Comment: +1 except use `perl` instead of `awk`. if you need something more complicated than grep/cut/sed, then chances are awk won't be enough and you need something "full-blown"

Comment: @sds why not python instead

Comment: @RetroCode: python is more "general purpose" than perl; the equivalent one-liner will probably be much longer.

Comment: @sds no, you don't need perl unless you're going to do something other than text processing. awk is just fine for the text processing stuff that's more complicated than grep/cut/sed and as a bonus comes as standard on all UNIX installations, unlike perl.

Comment: @RetroCode Because the CPython implementation's command line tool doesn't support being used as a filter for newline-terminated records, because it is more verbose, which is undesirable for one-liners, and because all regex modules I have tried with Python are 10 to 100 slower than Perl's, which is bad for large data.

Comment: Perl regexes can run in exponential time while awk always runs regexes in linear time. If regex speed is what you want, use grep or awk. Perl is a layer of hacks on top of each other while awk was carefully designed to be good at its primary task, which included keeping the language simple

For nontrivial matching where you want to capture a set of different patterns in a file and do different things for each, awk will also be noticeably more concise than perl. The awk textbook by its authors has the reader implement interpreters for several different small languages in awk

Comment: Also, these days Perl will very often not be installed on the system (It's not installed on my machine), while AWK is part of the posix spec and will pretty much always be available, even on busybox systems

Answer (score 14):

When only searching for strings, and speed matters, you should almost always use `grep`. It's orders of magnitude faster than `awk` when it comes to just gross searching.

*source [The functional and performance differences of sed, awk and other Unix parsing utilities](https://davidlyness.com/post/the-functional-and-performance-differences-of-sed-awk-and-other-unix-parsing-utilities)*

```
UTILITY    OPERATION TYPE      EXECUTION TIME     CHARACTERS PROCESSED PER SECOND
                               (10 ITERATIONS)
-------    --------------      ---------------    -------------------------------
grep       search only         41 sec.            489.3 million
sed        search & replace    4 min. 4 sec.      82.1 million
awk        search & replace    4 min. 46 sec.     69.8 million
Python     search & replace    4 min. 50 sec.     69.0 million
PHP        search & replace    15 min. 44 sec.    21.2 million
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice overview of all these programs. It really sheds light in the darkness.

Comment: ~headtilt~ PHP is on there but Perl isn't?

Comment: @Izkata - I thought the same thing when I saw this table a while ago.

Comment: @holasz - yeah this table really helped to understand the order in which you should try and use the big 3 (grep, sed, and awk).

Comment: Which `grep` and which `awk` are you refering to?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - the article that data is sourced from did not specify which versions. I've posted a comment asking, if I get any updates I'll include them here.

Comment: It's not really fair to the other utils that grep is just searching and they are also replacing.

Comment: @Kevin - yeah it's just to illustrate that in Unix there are specific tools for specific purposes, and just to be mindful of this when developing solutions.

Comment: Those are completely bogus numbers. Talk about comparing apples and oranges - it's like saying you can **only** find a new car on web site A in 5 secs whereas you can find a car, negotiate a price, get a loan, and purchase the car on site B in 1 hour so therefore site A is faster than site B.The article you quoted is completely wrong in it's statements of relative execution speed between grep, sed, and awk and it also says `awk ... has PCRE matching for regular expressions` which is just completely untrue.

Answer (score 6):

While I agree that in theory `grep` should be faster than `awk`, in practice, YMMV as that depends a lot on the implementation you use.

here comparing busybox 1.20.0's grep and awk, GNU grep 2.14, mawk 1.3.3, GNU awk 4.0.1 on Debian/Linux 7.0 amd64 (with glibc 2.17) in a UTF-8 locale on a 240MB file of 2.5M lines of ASCII-only characters.

```
$ time busybox grep error error | wc -l
331003
busybox grep error error  8.31s user 0.12s system 99% cpu 8.450 total
wc -l  0.07s user 0.11s system 2% cpu 8.448 total
$ time  busybox awk /error/ error | wc -l
331003
busybox awk /error/ error  2.39s user 0.84s system 98% cpu 3.265 total
wc -l  0.12s user 1.23s system 41% cpu 3.264 total
$ time  grep error error | wc -l
331003
grep error error  0.80s user 0.10s system 99% cpu 0.914 total
wc -l  0.00s user 0.11s system 12% cpu 0.913 total
$ time mawk /error/ error | wc -l
330803
mawk /error/ error  0.54s user 0.13s system 91% cpu 0.732 total
wc -l  0.03s user 0.08s system 14% cpu 0.731 total
$ time gawk /error/ error | wc -l
331003
gawk /error/ error  1.37s user 0.12s system 99% cpu 1.494 total
wc -l  0.04s user 0.07s system 7% cpu 1.492 total
$ time
```

In the C locale, only GNU grep gets a significant boost and becomes faster than `mawk`.

The dataset, the type of the regexp may also make a big difference. For regexps, `awk` should be compared to `grep -E` as `awk`'s regexps are extended REs.

For this dataset, `awk` could be faster than `grep` on busybox based systems or systems where `mawk` is the default `awk` and the default locale is UTF-8 based (IIRC, it used to be the case in Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, `grep` does one thing only as many other UNIX tools and that's matching a line to the given pattern and it does it well. On the other hand, `awk` is more sophisticated tool as it is a complete programming language defined by POSIX standard with typical features like variables, arrays, expressions, functions or control statements for pattern scanning and processing.

In my opinion, it depends on the implementation how both tools perform in case of pattern matching and on the  size of some input you want to process. I would expect that grep is usually more efficient than awk as it does matching only. But you can't write with grep a simple code to perform more complex tasks like further processing of matched records, computation or printing results without using other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk whenever you find yourself piping greps and seds and sorts and uniqs and the like. So instead of

```
grep <...> | sed <...> | sort <...> | cut <...> | head <...>
```

you should write

```
awk -e <...>
```

which has all these tool and (presumably) would perform better than forking subshells and executables with pipes.