# Extend grep to find a match after the first match

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a long list of strings separated by newlines and each section separated by a string starting with `~` (there are no other `~` in the file). I want to extend grep to find the `~` text right below the match.

Input:

```
abc
ads
acb
abc
acsa
acfs
~notthis
abc
ads
acb
xyz                <-- pattern
acsa
acfs
~this              <-- output
abc
ads
acb
abc
acsa
acfs
~no
```

Output when searching for `xyz`:

`~ this`

With `awk` I'd do something like

```
awk '/xyz/{x=1}x&&/~/{print;exit}' file
```

but I want to use grep if it can give me a performance advantage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least with GNU `grep 2.12`:

```
$ grep -Pzo 'xyz(?:.*\n)*?\K~this' file
~this
```

If your `grep` version does not allow `-P` with `-z`, you can use [pcregrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pcregrep) instead:

```
$ pcregrep -Mo 'xyz(?:.*\n)*?\K~this' file
~this
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get `grep: The -P and -z options cannot be combined` with `GNU grep 2.5.2`. Also, I don't know the text after `~` like you searched for `~this`- this is my desired output (I only know it's following a `~`)

Comment: I replaced `~this` in your pattern with `.*` and I get the right output, thanks. Do you know whether there's a performance disadvantage for using `pcregrep` instead of `grep`?

Comment: @confused00: In general, `grep` will a bit faster than `pcregrep`. But with UTF-8 character, `pcregrep` can take advantage. You should do a benchmark by yourself. You can also read this for a simple benchmark: http://rg03.wordpress.com/2009/09/09/gnu-grep-is-slow-on-utf-8/

Comment: I have a hard time to believe it is working. If one can use `~this` literally then simple `grep '~this' file` will do the job, but this is not the point, right? To my mind it should be `pcregrep -Mo 'xyz[^~]*?\K~.*' file | head -1`. Also I don't believe any kind of `grep` expression can beat `awk`.

Comment: @jimmij I mentioned in my 2nd comment that I replaced `~this` with `.*`

Comment: And after replacing `~this` to `.*` does it work as expected for you, i.e. returns `~this`? My version of pcregrep returns `~no` two times, what is understandable due to greedy nature of `*`, so one has to at least add `?` after `*`.

Comment: @jimmij You're right. I tested the code on a different input and I thought it worked fine, but indeed it gets the last match. Adding `?` fixes it, thanks

Comment: Test once again more carefully, most probably it matches many occurrences of the pattern, and you want only first, right?

Comment: @jimmij Okay I'm silly - I didn't mean to put `xyz` in my example input the 2nd time around, my pattern match is unique to the file. Sorry for that and thanks for pointing it out

Comment: jimmij and @confused00: Add `?` can make it match only the first after `xyz`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat "$file" | grep xyz -A 10000 | grep \~ -m1
```

or, equivalently,

```
grep -A 10000 xyz "$file" | grep -m1 '~'
```

Comment: This looks like it will produce the correct output, but I wonder whether it really performs better (i.e., runs faster) than awk. Have you tested that? Please post your benchmark results.

Comment: I have not benchmarked it but I found a link that says, basically, since awk has more to do per line that grep is faster https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88503/using-grep-vs-awk

Comment: Well, yeah, but the OP’s suggested command runs one `awk` process, and your answer runs *two* `grep` processes.  So this raises the question: *how much* faster is `grep` than `awk`?  Twice as fast?  Also, the OP’s command exits immediately upon finding the desired match, whereas yours potentially goes 9999 lines beyond it.